# Gradle Version Catalog and JavaFX

Tags: gradle, javafx, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I  am currently testing Version Catalog on a JavaFX project of mine. Therefore I need to update the dependencies and found something where I am stuck.

My dependencies are looking like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-base:11.0.2:win")
    implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11.0.2:win")
    implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11.0.2:win")
    implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11.0.2:win")
    implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-web:11.0.2:win")
}
```

I've created a `libs.versions.toml` file to reference the
dependencies later

```
[versions]
javafx-win = "11.0.2:win"

[libraries]
javafx-base-win = { module = "org.openjfx:javafx-base", version.ref = "javafx-win" }
javafx-controls-win = { module = "org.openjfx:javafx-controls", version.ref = "javafx-win" }
javafx-fxml-win = { module = "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml", version.ref = "javafx-win" }
javafx-graphics-win = { module = "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics", version.ref = "javafx-win" }
javafx-media-win = { module = "org.openjfx:javafx-media", version.ref = "javafx-win" }
javafx-web-win = { module = "org.openjfx:javafx-web", version.ref = "javafx-win" }


[bundles]
javafx-win = ["javafx-base-win", "javafx-controls-win", "javafx-fxml-win", "javafx-graphics-win",
  "javafx-media-win", "javafx-web-win"]
```

The problem that occurs now is that the depdendencies could not be found e.g.

```
dependencies {
   implementation(libs.bundles.javafx.win)
}
```

```
> Could not find org.openjfx:javafx-base:11.0.2-win.
        Searched in the following locations:
          - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2-win/javafx-base-11.0.2-win.pom
        If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
        Required by:
            project :
```

404  Not Found to the website: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2-win/javafx-base-11.0.2-win.pom

Probably this path should be correct:  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/

I would appreciate the help how I should configure the `toml`file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know Gradle, but some additional info anyway.  I think the path to the pom.xml is [https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/javafx-base-11.0.2.pom](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/javafx-base-11.0.2.pom).  There is no pom for `javafx-base-11.0.2-win.pom`.  The `-win` portion specifies the [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies): "The classifier distinguishes artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in content."

Comment: So what you need to do is to get both the unclassified jar [javafx-base-11.0.2.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/javafx-base-11.0.2.jar) and classified jar for the correct native library [javafx-base-11.0.2-win.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/javafx-base-11.0.2-win.jar) into your catalog (I have no idea how you would do that).  The unclassified code will be the cross-platform code for the library and the classified code will be the platform-specific code for the library: you need both to have a working app.

Comment: The problem is that I need the classifier in order to use jpms correctly. Without it, it won't work. I found out that it is not possible to specify the classier in the toml file but thanks for your reply.